# ELAN EM78P156NP microcntroller programming

Tags: c, programming, elan

I am writing program for ELAN EM78P156NP using WisePlus C Compiler ,but my program is not responding when written on micro controller.I am putting the code below please let me know what is wrong with the code.
I am just trying to blink the LED on PORT 5 and PORT 6 of the microcontroller
Please help me...

```
unsigned int PORT6 @0x06: rpage 0;
unsigned int PORT5 @0x05: rpage 0;
int delay()
{
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<1200;i++);
  return 0;
}

void main()
{
  PORT6=0x0000;
  PORT5=0x0000;
  while(1)
  {

   PORT6=0xffff;
   PORT5=0xffff;

   delay();
   PORT6=0x0000;
   PORT5=0x0000;

   delay();

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The power-on and RESET state of the IOC registers is all 1s, which means the port pins are high impedance, so they can't drive anything.

[image: http://www.digchip.com/datasheets/download_datasheet.php?id=2695786&part-number=EM78P156NP]

You need to read the chip datasheet carefully to see what has to be initialized or set up. **Never** assume the compiler does anything like that for you, only the minimum startup like clearing statics and such like. Hardware such as watch dog timers, ports, options, configuration is usually untouched and likely not what you want. Using a compiler does not mean you can ignore how the chip works, it means you have more things to understand.

There may be other things wrong- your delay loop will be very short unless your clock frequency is very low. Also, the registers are all 8 bits, not 16.

The EM78P156NP is an OTP processor- I hope you are using an emulator- otherwise you're going to have an enormous stack of useless chips.

Comment: Thank you Spehro Pefhany for your answer..actually I am a C and assemble programmer, working for the first time on these microcontrollers. Since there are almost 0 sample program available for these controllers I had not been able to make.                            I have added the changes u told as                          io unsigned int IOC6  @0x06: iopage 0; and initializing it as IOC6=0x00. will it work for me..Sorry if I annoyed you

Comment: No annoyance involved. I feel your pain. ;-)

Comment: AFAIK, the Elan microcontrollers are clones of the much more reputable / famous Microchip PIC microcontrollers. So if you want sample code, search for code written for the PIC micros. Your EM78P156NP [seems to be](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31696/example-projects-programming-and-debugging-tools-to-work-with-elan-em78-series) compatible with Microchip PIC 16C54/55/56 micros.